# STM32F411 DWT CYCCNT counter width

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

For some time I have been using the DWT cycle counter, CYCCNT in STM32F4 processors for timing operations. Everywhere I look, the assumption is that this is a 32 bit counter.

However, I am now using the STM32F411CE processor and it looks to me like there are only 31 bits. 
I run this code:

```
CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
DWT->CTRL |= 1; 
uint32_t next = millis()+200;
DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
while(1){
  while(next > millis()){
  // do nothing
  }
  next += 200;
  printf("%8lu %12lu\n",next,DWT->CYCCNT);
}
```

And observe the results on the terminal. The processor is running at 100MHz, so the counter increases by 20 million after 200ms. After a while the counter value wraps but it wraps at 2^31, not 2^32:

```
21435   2039916353
21635   2059916353
21835   2079916353
22035   2099916353
22235   2119916353
22435   2139916341
22635     12432705
22835     32432705
23035     52432705
23235     72432705
```

So, can anyone point me to any definitive information about the CYCCNT counter width on the STM32F411 processor? Or have I overlooked something embarrassingly simple?

UPDATE:

I ran the exact same code on a board containing an STM32F405 processor and got these results:

```
30419   4204732031
30619   4233532031
30819   4262332031
31019   4291132031
31219     24964735
31419     53764738
31619     82564738
31819    111364735
```

So it seems clear to me that the '405 processor CYCCNT register *is* 32 bit whereas the '411 processor is only 31 bit. Most odd!

UPDATE2:

A second board with the same processor type behaves perfectly as well. A friend also ran the code on his (different) '411 board with no problems. It now seems that the board itself is faulty or, possibly, the processor is broken. All the other processor functions appear correct. Looks like it is just time to swap out the processor.

Comment: How strange. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

The description of DWT_CYCCNT is in section C1.8.8 of the Arm V7m Architecture Reference manual which you can get from [here](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0403/e/armv7-m-architecture-reference-manual)

Section C1.8.3 says

> CYCCNT is an optional free-running 32-bit cycle counter.
>
> When implemented and enabled, CYCCNT increments on each cycle of the processor clock. When the counter
>   overflows it wraps to zero, transparently.

So this doesn't explain your findings.

Comment: Thanks for the link. At least now I know it is _supposed_ to be 32 bit.